# uploading sql ddl file to postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, ubuntu-12.04, ddl

I created this SQL file and I want to upload this DDL (Data Definition Language) File to my PostgreSQL server.  My server currently runs on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
CREATE DATABASE *;

--Create Tables
CREATE TABLE USER(
    user_id      varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    username     varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    user_type    varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    name         varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    email        varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    picture      varchar(36)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
    product_id           varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_name         varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_type         varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_price        varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_available    varchar(36)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION(
    transaction_id    varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    user_id           varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_id        varchar(36)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE INVENTORY(
    product_id           varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_name         varchar(36)    NOT NULL,
    product_available    varchar(36)    NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Running the script

To run DDL in the form of an SQL script, you should use `psql`, the same command you use to connect to the server interactively.

```
psql -h the.server.hostname -f my_script.sql the_database
```

I recommend using `ON_ERROR_STOP=1` and `-1`, so it runs the DDL in a single transaction and aborts on any error.

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -1 -h the.server.hostname -f my_script.sql the_database
```

### Creating the DB

You can't create the database then immediately start creating tables. You must connect to some other DB to run `create database` and if you've connected to another DB, that's where the tables will get created.

You can put the `psql` command `\c databasename` in after the `CREATE DATABASE`, so it'll create the DB then switch to it. But it's generally a bad idea: if the create fails, the script will merrily keep on creating tables in the wrong DB unless you use `ON_ERROR_STOP`.  You also can't use `-1` (run in a single transaction) if you create and switch to a new DB.

Instead, manually `CREATE DATABASE` first, or do it with a separate script. That way you can run your DDL script sensibly.

### The DDL

Your schema needs some work.

No primary keys.

No foreign keys.

Use of `varchar(36)` everywhere, even where it's wildly inappropriate like names and email addresses. Use the unbounded `text` type, or `varchar` with no length (they're the same thing in PostgreSQL anyway) if you don't have a need to constrain the length of a field for a specific reason.